# Jquery load function, function on loaded load not working

Tags: php, jquery

I have a function where you click on something and then a resizable div toggles with content loaded (`.load` function).

```
$("#menucontent").load("loader.php?c=menup");
$("#menucontent").draggable();
$("#menuc").click(function(){
$("#menucontent").toggle(); //
$("#menucontent").resizable();
});
```

Basically this loads the data from loader.php to the div with id menuc.
So far so good.. Data retrieved from loader.php :

```
echo '<a class="offertezoek" href="#">ZOEK OFFERTE<div style="display:none;" id="offertezoek"><input type="text" id="offertezoek" name="offertezoek">TEST</div></a><br /><br />';
```

Now the problem comes, I want to create a function for the data loaded.
The data gets loaded but the function does not work.

Is this because the page is already ready and Jquery executed all the javascript before the data was in the div offertezoek (got added afterwards with `.load("loader.php")` ??

NEW FUNCTION :

```
$(".offertezoek").click(function(){
$("#offertezoek").toggle(); //
});
```

Comment: You can pass a callback to the load function. If a callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks I think this also should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.offertezoek', function(){
   $("#offertezoek").toggle(); //
});
```

Comment: .live() may work better in case of jquery dynamically loaded content.

Comment: Thanks, this works great ! Can you explain me why ? Was I thinking in the right direction ?

Comment: @Mikhail, `live()` is deprecated since 1.7

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail. How do you mean .live instead of .on ? What is the difference. I thought .on function was only for old Jquery versions.

Comment: @dr3 Don't use live, it's deprecated.

Comment: @dr3 The opposite- `on()` is new, `.live()` is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. For why this works, see the jquery api documenation for `.on`

Comment: Yes it adds an event handler to the document. But $(".offertezoek").click(function()also attaches an event handler to the class offertezoek, right ? I don't see the difference.

Comment: @dr3 it attaches an event handler to the elements with class offertezoek, but you have no one at that time, they are loaded only after

Comment: Ok get it. The .on adds the new event (toggle) to the click action everytime it runs instead of just once when loading the javascript and there is no class offertezoek at that time.